# React shows wrong data. I guess it just dont update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React shows wrong data. I guess it just dont update.
I cant solve this problem for 2 days. Help please.
What is wrong here? I tried to fix componentdidmount but unfortunatelly it didn't help

```
class Table extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state  = {data: []}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.data = setInterval(() =>
                console.log(this.setState({data})),
                this.setState(
            fetch('/lk/reports/3/month-ajax')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => this.setState({data})))
            , 50);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.data);


    }


    render() {
        if (this.state.data.length == 0) {
            return (<div className="table-wrapper mt-5 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <i className="fas fa-spinner fa-3x fa-fw fa-spin"></i>
            </div>);
        } else {
            return (
        
               <table className="table highlight responsive-table">
                     <thead className="teal lighten-4">
                          <tr>
                                     
                                                <th>{this.state.data.time}</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                            {this.state.data.kpi.map(item => <tr className={this.activeRow(item)}>

                                                <td>{item.client}</td>
                                                <td>{item.all_incidents}</td>
                                            </tr>)}
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Here is full react.js code
Thank you!

Comment: what you are trying to achieve here ? what is expected ? please be clear

Comment: Making an API call inside "setState" is not recommended.  You can call setState once you have success in your fetch call. If you are trying to print state of the component, you should reference it by "console.log(this.state)" not by "console.log(this.setState({data}))".  Could you please be clear with your probelm and code that you are pasting.